# Can’t send email to smtp.gmail.com

Tags: smtp, camunda, camunda-modeler

Here is my mail configuration:

```
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory

mail.store.protocol=imaps
mail.imaps.host=imap.gmail.com
mail.imaps.port=993
mail.imaps.timeout=10000

mail.poll.folder=INBOX
mail.sender=Camunda
mail.attachment.download=true

mail.user=“"
mail.password="”
```

and then i have added http-connector for send-mail it looks like this:
[image]
but i can’t send any mails , by the way i can’t get any errors what should i change?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that gmail flagged this as a "Less secure app". Check your inbox for a message with the subject: "Review blocked sign-in attempt".  If that's the case you can either adjust this account to allow less secure apps (https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).

Comment: I  have  turned  on less secure  apps, could  there  be any kind  of  configuration  which  should  i make  to enable message receiving